# Default values from different layer in QGIS 3 - kind of spatial join

Tags: qgis-3, default-value

Is there a way to set the default value in QGIS 3 Properties - Attribute Forms based on the values of a different layer.
E.g. I set a point and the fields for e.g. country and height are filled out based on the position of the point and the values other layers.

Comment: Your *Other solutions...* postscript is confusing, making the Question either *too broad* or *unclear*

Comment: edited. Just a hint I am not stuck to this way.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to set a default value based on an expression, and you can write an expression that references the attributes of different layers. Have a look at the built-in `aggregate` functions. If you have trouble with those, install the RefFunctions plugin to gain access to some custom functions which are a bit easier to use.